# How to continue gradle build after a delete task fails?

Tags: java, eclipse, groovy, gradle

Currently I have this gradle.build file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
clean.doFirst {
    delete "build"
    delete "bin"
    delete "out.log"
    try {
        delete "target"
    } catch (TaskExecutionException e) {
        //probably no permission to delete Eclipse's target folder
    }
}
```

The `delete "target"` is very likely to fail because it is generated by Eclipse and doesn't have delete permission by default. If `delete "target"` fails I want the build to continue anyway.

How do I do that? The try-catch doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

As for the whole task, you can use a `--continue` flag with the name of the clean task, when running the build from cli, which is, according to [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_command_line.html):

> Continues task execution after a task failure.

Or you can set the task property `ignoreFailures` to true. One possible problem with this solutions is, that this will ignore all the delete failures, not only the deletion of target. May be you have to separate this task into 2, because they have a little bit different behaviour and you are able to ignore one of them.